# Unable to modify Status Code of appointment

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In order to meet a client requirment, I need to modify the status and status reason fields of the entity appointment in CRM 2011.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add more status values to appointment.

From the UI, you can add only add or edit status reasons for the open status.

If you want to add status reasons for other statuses, you can use an [InsertStatusValueRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.insertstatusvaluerequest(v=crm.5).aspx).

```cs
var insertStatusValueRequest =
    new InsertStatusValueRequest
{
    AttributeLogicalName = "statuscode",
    EntityLogicalName = Appointment.EntityLogicalName,
    Label = new Label("Not-Done", _languageCode),
    StateCode = 1
};
_serviceProxy.Execute(insertStatusValueRequest);
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response, actually how can we also edit existing StatusCode and to what message we need to register this plugin to ?

Comment: Use [UpdateOptionValueRequest](http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2014/05/dynamics-crm-managing-appointment-status-reasons.html) for updating existing status reasons. Why are you talking about plugins?

Comment: " I'm newbie to CRM " where this code is supposed to be ?  we need to create a plugin, can you provide the whole procedure to achieve these changes please

Comment: You don't need to deploy your code to CRM as a plugin. It is sufficient to run it from Visual Studio on your developer machine. Alternatively you could look at using [Code Now](http://www.itaintboring.com/tcs-tools/code-now-plugin-for-xrmtoolbox/) in XrmToolBox, though I have not personally tried it.